# In a Swift Class how do I use a @Published instance member within a property initializer

Tags: swift, instance-variables, completionhandler

I am trying to use a completion handler in a view model that assigns values to @Published variables.  I get an error stating I cannot use instance members within the property initializer.  I tried adding these variables to the class init with no success.  If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.  Below is the view model.

```
class VOOViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isloading: Bool
    @Published var vooValues1: [TradingDayPrices]
    var vooTempValues1: [TradingDayPrices] = []
    let dataContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    var vooCompactDataString: String = ""
    var vooCompactDataArray: [IndexFund] = []
    var vooContainerEmpty: Bool = false
    var updatedVOODataAvailable: Bool = false
    var latestVOOArrayDate: Date = Date()
    var latestVOOContainerDate: Date = Date()
    var vooFullDataString: String = ""
    var vooFullDataArray: [IndexFund] = []
    init() {
        isloading = true
        vooValues1 = []
        dataContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Index Funds")
        dataContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data Failed to Load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }  // end if let
        }  // end load persistent stores
        SetupVOO(using: vooCompletionHandler)
    } // end init
    let vooCompletionHandler: ([TradingDayPrices], Bool) -> Void = { prices, loadingComplete in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            vooValues1 = prices
// Error = Cannot use instance member 'vooValues1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
            isloading = loadingComplete
// Error = Cannot use instance member 'isloading' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
        }
    }
    func SetupVOO(using completionHandler: ([TradingDayPrices], Bool) -> Void) {
        Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
            do {
                vooCompactDataString = try await GetOnlineDataAA(urlString: URLStrings.VOOCompact)
                vooCompactDataArray = await ConvertStringToArrayAA(stringData: vooCompactDataString)
                let vooContainerEmpty = await IsDataContainerEmptyAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, fundName: "VOO")
                if vooContainerEmpty == true {
                    updatedVOODataAvailable = true
                } else {
                    latestVOOArrayDate = await GetLatestArrayDateAA(dataArray: vooCompactDataArray)
                    latestVOOContainerDate = await GetLatestContainerDateAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, fundName: "VOO")
                    if latestVOOArrayDate > latestVOOContainerDate {
                        updatedVOODataAvailable = true
                        await DeleteContainerDataAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, fundName: "VOO")
                    } // end if
                } // end else
                if updatedVOODataAvailable == true {
                    vooFullDataString = try await GetOnlineDataAA(urlString: URLStrings.VOOFull)
                    vooFullDataArray = await ConvertStringToArrayAA(stringData: vooFullDataString)
                    await UpdatePersistentStoreAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, fundName: "VOO", dataArray: vooFullDataArray)
                    await NormalizeDatesAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, numYears: 1, latestDate: latestVOOArrayDate, fundName: "VOO")
                    await NormalizeDatesAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, numYears: 5, latestDate: latestVOOArrayDate, fundName: "VOO")
                    await NormalizeClosingValuesAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, numYears: 1, latestDate: latestVOOArrayDate, fundName: "VOO")
                    await NormalizeClosingValuesAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, numYears: 5, latestDate: latestVOOArrayDate, fundName: "VOO")
                } // end if statement
                vooTempValues1 = await FetchContainerValuesAA(moc: dataContainer.viewContext, numYears: 1, latestDate: latestVOOArrayDate, fundName: "VOO")
            } catch {
                print("Error getting VOO data")
            } // end catch
        } // end task
        completionHandler(vooTempValues1, false)
    } // end func
} // end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to make `vooCompletionHandler` into a function:

```
func vooCompletionHandler(prices: [TradingDayPrices], loadingComplete: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        vooValues1 = prices
        isloading = loadingComplete
    }
}
```

You'd use the function the same way in `SetupVOO(using: vooCompletionHandler)`